# Finding minimum in sublists in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
data=np.array([[ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
       [ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
       [-3.590e+00, -1.448e+00],
       [ 3.642e-02,  4.813e-02],
       [ 2.149e+02,  2.186e+02],
       [ 6.147e+01,  6.633e+01],
       [ 3.733e-02,  4.821e-02],
       [ 2.131e+02,  2.186e+02],
       [ 6.205e+01,  6.633e+01],
       [-4.220e-01, -7.210e-02],
       [ 2.110e-09,  6.797e-10],
       [ 1.198e-11,  2.675e-12],
       [ 1.603e+02,  1.362e+02]])
```

I need the minimum for each row. To do so I did the following:

```
[min(x) for x in data]

[0.0,
 0.0,
 -3.59,
 0.03642,
 214.9,
 61.47,
 0.03733,
 213.1,
 62.05,
 -0.422,
 6.797e-10,
 2.675e-12,
 136.2]
```

Do you know another solution which does not use a for loop?

Comment: `data.min(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [numpy.min](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) method which accepts a parameter for the `axis`:

```py
import numpy as np

data=np.array([[ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
       [ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
       [-3.590e+00, -1.448e+00],
       [ 3.642e-02,  4.813e-02],
       [ 2.149e+02,  2.186e+02],
       [ 6.147e+01,  6.633e+01],
       [ 3.733e-02,  4.821e-02],
       [ 2.131e+02,  2.186e+02],
       [ 6.205e+01,  6.633e+01],
       [-4.220e-01, -7.210e-02],
       [ 2.110e-09,  6.797e-10],
       [ 1.198e-11,  2.675e-12],
       [ 1.603e+02,  1.362e+02]])

data.min(axis=1)
```

It gives the following output:

```
array([ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00, -3.590e+00,  3.642e-02,  2.149e+02,
        6.147e+01,  3.733e-02,  2.131e+02,  6.205e+01, -4.220e-01,
        6.797e-10,  2.675e-12,  1.362e+02])
```